# What is the probability of 2 players meeting during a random knockout tennis tournament?

Tags: probability

A tennis tournament has $n$ players. $n$ is an even number. Each round, we randomly pair two players and all players have the same ability and the winner is random. All winners go to the next round and are paired up again randomly. We repeat this process until one player left as the champion.

Say we have two players $A$ and $B$, what's the probability that $A$ meet $B$ during the entire tournament?

For the answer, I get that 1) we need $n-1$ games in total to eliminate $n-1$ players 2) there is $C^{n}_{2}$ way to match $2$ players.
What I don't understand is why the answer is $\frac{(n-1)}{C^{n}_{2}}$.

Isn't that $C^{n}_{2}$ is only for the first round when we still have $n$ players? For the second round, if $A$ and $B$ still stay in the game, but the number of the plays in the game has been reduced to $0.5n$, so $C^{0.5n}_{2}$ is probability for $A$ to meet $B$? And if any of $A$ or $B$ got knocked out, they will never meet? What I don't get is, the denominator only holds before any matches start right? once the game started and getting the n-1 games, in each round, the probability for A meet B is different, correct?

Comment: The probability can't be $_nC_2(n-1)$, since that would be a number much greater than $1$.  There are $_nC_2$ different pairings, of which only $n-1$ actually meet.  By symmetry, the probability that $A$ and $B$ meet is just $\frac{n-1}{_nC_2}$.

Comment: But what if it started with $30$ players? The next round would have $15$ players remaining, which is odd

Comment: Actually, normally $n$ has to be of the form $2^k$ to avoid byes and so on. Assuming a normal tournament, like any grand slam, say, there is a symmetry.

Comment: @trueblueanil Unsure why Brian Tung used the adjective *symmetry*.   Neither the analysis in his comment, nor the analysis in my answer actually depend on any considerations of symmetry.  That is, if there were $(103)$ players entered into the tournament, the chance of any two of them meeting would be $\frac{2}{103}.$

Comment: @user71207 see my previous comment to trueblueanil. In your example, with $(n=30)$, there will be 15 meetings in the 1st round, and only 7 in the 2nd round.  The player getting a bye in the 2nd round meets with no one.  When $(n=30)$ it is assumed that there are $(29)$ matches, or adopting the syntax in my answer, $(58)$ *man-meetings*.

Comment: @BrianTung I corrected the answer in the OP. What I still don't get is, the denominator only holds before any matches start right? once the game started and getting the n-1 games, in each round, the probability for A meet B is different, correct?

Comment: @Lisa "the denominator only holds before any matches start right? once the game started and getting the $n-1$ games, in each round, the probability for $A$ meet $B$ is different, correct?" : See the Addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing we need to remember is that there are $n-1$ matches, each one between a different pair of opponents, and the possible sequences of events are completely symmetrical: for any possible history of the tournament (who played whom in each pairing of each round), any permutation of the player's roles in that history is equally likely to have occurred. In particular, no two players are more likely to meet than any other two players.

Give the players identifying numbers from $1$ to $n$ inclusive.
For $1 \leq j < k \leq n,$ let $X_{j,k}$ be $1$ if player number $j$ ever plays player $k$ during the tournament, $0$ otherwise.
Then $X_{j,k}$ is a Bernoulli random variable.

Since each $X_{j,k}$ is a Bernoulli variable, $E(X_{j,k}) = P(X_{j,k} = 1)$.
Since no two players are more likely to meet than any other two players,
no probability $P(X_{j,k} = 1)$ is greater than any other, so no expected value is greater than any other, and therefore
$$ E(X_{1,2}) = E(X_{1,3}) = E(X_{2,3}) = \cdots = E(X_{n-1,n}). $$

There are $C_2^n$ such variables $X_{j,k}$. Their sum is

$$ Y = X_{1,2} + X_{1,3} + X_{2,3} + \cdots + X_{n-1,n} = n - 1 $$

because exactly $n - 1$ pairs must play, $X_{j,k} = 1$ for each of those pairs, and
$X_{j,k} = 0$ for every other pair.

By linearity of expectation,
\begin{multline}
E(X_{1,2}) + E(X_{1,3}) + E(X_{2,3}) + \cdots + E(X_{n-1,n}) \\
= E(X_{1,2} + X_{1,3} + X_{2,3} + \cdots + X_{n-1,n}) = n - 1
\end{multline}
since the expectation of a constant is just the constant.

But since the expected values of $E(X_{j,k})$ for each pair of players are all equal,
$$ E(X_{1,2}) + E(X_{1,3}) + E(X_{2,3}) + \cdots + E(X_{n-1,n}) = C_2^n E(X_{A,B}) $$
where $A$ and $B$ are the numbers assigned to the two players in the question.

That is,
$$ C_2^n E(X_{A,B}) = n - 1, $$
therefore
$$ P(X_{A,B} = 1) = E(X_{A,B}) = \frac{n - 1}{C_2^n} $$

And of course $P(X_{A,B} = 1)$ is the probability that $A$ and $B$ meet.

Answer (score 2):

Addendum added to respond to a comment/question.

---

**original answer**

Alternative approach that is very similar to Brian Tung's comment, which immediately followed the question.

Each time that a match is played, there are two *man-meetings*: For example, if A plays B, then A has met with a person and B has met with a person.

There will be a total of $(n-1)$ matches played.  This means that there will be a total of $2(n-1)$ *man-meetings* that occur.  Since there are $n$ people, each person, will on average, experience $\frac{2(n-1)}{n}$ man meetings.

This means that the chance that a given person's man meetings include a specific one of the other $(n-1)$ people is

$$\frac{2(n-1)}{n} \times \frac{1}{n-1} = \frac{2}{n}.$$

---

---

**Addendum**
Responding to a comment question:

> What I still don't get is, the denominator only holds before any matches start right? once the game started and getting the $n-1$ games, in each round, the probability for $A$ meet $B$ is different, correct?

Yes, the probability for $A$ and $B$ to meet, does change, round by round.  The original question was to compute the *overall* chance of $A$ and $B$ meeting anywhere in the tournament.  This overall chance has been computed as $(2/n)$, where $n$ is the number of original players.

The same answer, $(2/n),$ can be computed by a direct round by round examination of the tournament.  The approach is much less elegant, but still do-able.  I will illustrate with two examples: $(n=16)$ and $(n=10)$.

---

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~n=16}$

For Round $1$:
There are $\binom{16}{2}$ possible pairings, of which $8$ will occur in Round $1$.  Therefore, the chance of $A$ and $B$ meeting in Round $1$ are 
$\displaystyle \frac{8}{\binom{16}{2}} = \frac{2 \times 8}{16 \times 15} = \frac{1}{15}.$

Note that since the number of players is $n = 2^4$, the tournament will have $4$ rounds.

For $k \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, I will let $T_k$ denote the probability of $A,B$ meeting in Round $k$.  Then, the overall probability will be $T_1 + T_2 + T_3 + T_4.$

For Round $1$, $T_1$ has been computed as
$$T_1 = \frac{1}{15}.$$

I will also employ *helper* variables $S_1, S_2, S_3$, where $S_k$ will represent the probability that $A,B$ were not paired together in Round $k$, **given** that they each made it to Round $k$.

Here, $$S_1 = 1 - \frac{1}{15}  = \frac{14}{15}.$$

---

In order to meet in Round $2$, several things must happen.

- They must not meet in Round $1$, but must each survive Round $1$. 
  The chances of this happening are
  $\displaystyle \frac{14}{15} \times \frac{1}{4}.$
- They must be paired together in Round $2$, which will have $4$ pairings out of a possible $\binom{8}{2}$.  The chances of them being paired together are therefore 
  $\displaystyle \frac{4}{\binom{8}{2}} = \frac{4 \times 2}{8 \times 7} = \frac{1}{7}.$

Therefore

$$T_2 = \frac{14}{15} \times \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{7} = \frac{1}{30}.$$

Further, since $(1/7)$ is the chance that they were paired together in Round $2$, assuming that they made it that far, then

$$S_2 = 1 - (1/7) = (6/7).$$

---

In order to meet in Round $3$, several things must happen.

- They must not meet in Round $1$, but must each survive Round $1$. 
  The chances of this happening are
  $\displaystyle \frac{14}{15} \times \frac{1}{4}.$
- Then, they must not meet in Round $2$, but must each survive Round $2$. 
  The chances of this happening are
  $\displaystyle \frac{6}{7} \times \frac{1}{4}.$
- They must be paired together in Round $3$, which will have $2$ pairings out of a possible $\binom{4}{2}$.  The chances of them being paired together are therefore 
  $\displaystyle \frac{2}{\binom{4}{2}} = \frac{2 \times 2}{4 \times 3} = \frac{1}{3}.$

Therefore

$$T_3 = \frac{14}{15} \times \frac{1}{4} \times 
\frac{6}{7} \times \frac{1}{4} \times 
\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{60}.$$

Further, since $(1/3)$ is the chance that they were paired together in Round $3$, assuming that they made it that far, then

$$S_3 = 1 - (1/3) = (2/3).$$

---

In order to meet in Round $4$, several things must happen.

- They must not meet in Round $1$, but must each survive Round $1$. 
  The chances of this happening are
  $\displaystyle \frac{14}{15} \times \frac{1}{4}.$
- Then, they must not meet in Round $2$, but must each survive Round $2$. 
  The chances of this happening are
  $\displaystyle \frac{6}{7} \times \frac{1}{4}.$
- Then, they must not meet in Round $3$, but must each survive Round $3$. 
  The chances of this happening are
  $\displaystyle \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{4}.$
- They must be paired together in Round $4$.  Since Round $4$ will be the championship match, Round $4$ will only have 1 pairing.  Therefore, if $A,B$ each make it to Round $4$, then they are certain to meet.

Therefore

$$T_4 = \frac{14}{15} \times \frac{1}{4} \times 
\frac{6}{7} \times \frac{1}{4} \times 
\frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{120}.$$

---

Therefore, the overall chances are $T_1 + T_2 + T_3 + T_4$ which equals

$$\frac{1}{15} + \frac{1}{30} + \frac{1}{60} + \frac{1}{120}$$

$$= \frac{8 + 4 + 2 + 1}{120} = \frac{15}{120} = 
\frac{1}{8} = \frac{2}{16} = \frac{2}{n}.$$

---

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~n=10}$
This will be somewhat complicated by the fact that $n=10$ is not a power of $2$ (e.g. such as $16 = 2^4$).  Therefore, some of the Rounds will feature a player being given a **bye**, where they are automatically passed to the next round.  Note that when a player is given a bye, for a specific round, they don't play anyone during that round.

As in the case of $n = 16$, I will let $T_k$ denote the chance of $A,B$ meeting in Round $k$.

If Round $k$ features a bye, then I will let $R_k$ denote the chance that any player receives a bye, and I will then let $S_k$ denote the chance of $A,B$ not meeting in Round $k$, given that they each made it to Round $k$, and also given that **neither of them are given a bye** for Round $k$.

Alternatively, if Round $k$ does not feature a bye, then I will let $S_k$ denote the chance of $A,B$ not meeting in Round $k$, given that they each made it to Round $k$.

For Round $1$:
There are $\binom{10}{2}$ possible pairings, of which $5$ will occur in Round $1$.  Therefore, the chance of $A$ and $B$ meeting in Round $1$ are

$$T_1 = \frac{5}{\binom{10}{2}} = \frac{2 \times 5}{10 \times 9} = \frac{1}{9}.$$

$$S_1 = 1 - \frac{1}{9}  = \frac{8}{9}.$$

---

In order to meet in Round $2$, several things must happen.

- They must not meet in Round $1$, but must each survive Round $1$. 
  The chances of this happening are
  $\displaystyle \frac{8}{9} \times \frac{1}{4}.$
- With Round $2$ having $5$ players, a bye will be given.  Therefore, in order for $A,B$ to meet, neither of them must be given a bye.  The chances of neither $A,B$ being given a bye are $\displaystyle \frac{3}{5}.$
- Assuming that neither of $A,B$ are given a Round $2$ bye, they must be paired together in Round $2$.  With the Round $2$ bye person eliminated from consideration, Round $2$ will have $2$ pairings out of a possible $\binom{4}{2}$.  The chances of $A,B$ being paired together in Round $2$, assuming that neither of $A,B$ are given a bye in Round $2$, are therefore 
  $\displaystyle \frac{2}{\binom{4}{2}} = \frac{1}{3}.$

Therefore

$$T_2 = \frac{8}{9} \times \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{3}{5} \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{45}.$$

Here, $$R_2 = \frac{1}{5} ~~~\text{and}~~~ S_2 = 1 - (1/3) = (2/3).$$

---

In order to meet in Round $3$, several things must happen.

- They must not meet in Round $1$, but must each survive Round $1$. 
  The chances of this happening are
  $\displaystyle \frac{8}{9} \times \frac{1}{4}.$
- Then, they must not meet in Round $2$, but must each survive Round $2$. 
  This computation is complicated by the possibility that one of $A,B$ was given a bye in Round $2$.  If either one of them was given a bye, then only one of them played a match.  Therefore, the chances of them both surviving because one of them was given a bye is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{2}{5} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{5}.$ 
  Alternatively, if neither was given a bye, they would have had to both survive without having played each other.  The probability that this happened is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{3}{5} \times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{10}.$ 
  Therefore, assuming that $A,B$ both made it to Round $2$ without playing each other, the probability of them both surviving Round $2$ without playing each other is 
  $\displaystyle\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{10} = \frac{3}{10}.$
- They must be paired together in Round $3$, which will have $3$ people.  Round $3$ will therefore have 1 bye and 1 pairing.  Therefore, the chances of them being paired here are 
  $\displaystyle \frac{1}{3}.$

Therefore

$$T_3 = \frac{8}{9} \times \frac{1}{4} \times 
\frac{3}{10} \times 
\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{45}.$$

Further, assuming that they made it to Round $3$, then the chance of either one receiving a bye is $(1/3)$ and the chance that they then played each other, if neither was given a bye is $(1/1).$

Here, $$R_3 = \frac{1}{3} ~~~\text{and}~~~ S_3 = 0.$$

---

In order to meet in Round $4$, several things must happen.

- They must not meet in Round $1$, but must each survive Round $1$. 
  The chances of this happening are
  $\displaystyle \frac{8}{9} \times \frac{1}{4}.$
- Then, they must not meet in Round $2$, but must each survive Round $2$. 
  As analyzed in the previous section, the chances of this happening are 
  $\frac{3}{10}.$
- They must not meet in Round $3$, but each must survive Round $3$.  The only way that this can happen is if one of them is given a bye in Round $3$.  
  The chance of that happening is $\displaystyle \frac{2}{3}.$
  When it does happen, only one of them is playing a match, with a survival chance for that person of $\frac{1}{2}.$ 
  Therefore, the relevant computation here is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{3}.$
- Having each made it to Round $4$, they must then play each other in Round $4$.  Since Round $4$ is the championship round, this is a certainty, assuming that they both make it to Round $4$.

Therefore

$$T_4 = \frac{8}{9} \times \frac{1}{4} \times 
\frac{3}{10} \times 
\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{45}.$$

---

Therefore, the overall chances are $T_1 + T_2 + T_3 + T_4$ which equals

$$\frac{1}{9} + \frac{2}{45} + \frac{1}{45} + \frac{1}{45}$$

$$= \frac{5 + 2 + 1 + 1}{45} = 
\frac{9}{45} = \frac{1}{5} = \frac{2}{10} = \frac{2}{n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

(1) Since there are $n$ players, and exactly $1$ player is eliminated from each match, there need to be a total of $n-1$ matches played.

(2) Before playing any matches, there is an $1/{n\choose 2}$ chance that any two random players will meet in any one match.

Thus there is $(n-1)\frac{1}{{n\choose 2}}$ chance that any two players will meet in the tournament (since there are $n-1$ matches for them to meet in, with a probability $1/C^n_2$ in each match).

It can also be thought of as you have a $1/C^n_2$ chance of satisfying the criterion (players $A$ and $B$ meet) and you get $n-1$ chances (before any matches are played).

Comment: I updated the post to correct the under, I guess where I'm confused is the denominator only holds before any matches start, when there're still n players in the game, right? once the game started and getting the n-1 games, in each round, the probability for A meet B is different, correct? @Stacker

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about a fixed initial configuration, in which case the probability that A and B meet would be the condition that they win all their matches before meeting at a predetermined spot that they would have to meet at. But this argument simply states that there are $n-1$ possible places they could meet and at probability $1/{n\choose 2}$ at each place, irrespective of whatever initial configuration.